# Draw overlapping lines with same transparency

Tags: c#, graphics, gdi+

I have roughly this logic:

```
Bitmap bmp = ....
Pen pen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(125, 0, 0, 255), 15);
var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
graphics.DrawLines(pen, points1);
graphics.DrawLines(pen, points2);
```

The problem is, that points1 and points2 contain some line segments that are overlaping.

If I draw this lines, the overlapping part have a different color then the rest, due to the blending of the same segments (first, 1 with background and later 2 with already blended 1 with background). Is there a way, how to achieve the effect, that the overlapping parts have the same color as a single non-overlapping segmens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DrawLines` will not work in this case as it will only draw **connected** lines in **one** go.

You need to add the line sets to **one** `GraphicsPath` using `StartFigure` to **separate** the two sets.

Example, `Drawline` to the left, `DrawPath` to the right:

[image]

Here is the code for both:

```
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
..
Pen pen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(125, 0, 0, 255), 15)
   { LineJoin = LineJoin.Round };
var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
graphics.Clear(Color.White);
graphics.DrawLines(pen, points1);
graphics.DrawLines(pen, points2);
bmp.Save("D:\\__x19DL", ImageFormat.Png);

graphics.Clear(Color.White);
using (GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath())
{
    gp.AddLines(points1);
    gp.StartFigure();
    gp.AddLines(points2);
    graphics.DrawPath(pen, gp);
    bmp.Save("D:\\__x19GP", ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

Don't forget to `Dispose` of the `Pen` and the `Graphics` object, or, better, put them in `using` clauses!